# how can I predict the next 3 values with rolling average and not create new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily data and I want to EXTEND it (not create a new column) by using a rolling mean of the previous 3 values.  After creating that value I want to be able to use it to predict the following, etc...
This is my data:

```
Date         Value
6/1/2020     15
6/2/2020     12
6/3/2020     14
6/4/2020     15
6/5/2020     10
```

I want to extend the dataframe with the rolling mean (window =3) each time:

```
Date         Value
6/1/2020     15
6/2/2020     12
6/3/2020     14
6/4/2020     15
6/5/2020     10
6/6/2020     13
6/7/2020     12.7
6/8/2020     11.9
....
```

I know pandas has a rolling mean function, but I don't want to create a new column, I want to extend my existing dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an empty dictionary for date and value.
Then, set the date = the last date + 1.
Then, calculate the average of last three from column 2 and assign the value to the value in the dictionary.
Now, you would have something like `new_row = {'date': '6/9/2020', 'value': 12.3}`
Lastly, append the dictionary to the table as the last row, which can be used to calculate the next row.

Comment: How can I program that?